# Объединение std::array с помощью вариативных шаблонов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Мне нужно, чтобы я могла объединять несколько std::array в один, причем с использованием вариативных шаблонов.
Мне удалось сделать объединение двух std::array, но если я пытаюсь объединить три - выдает ошибку.
Ниже представлен код и соответствующая ошибка.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, long unsigned N>
auto cat(array < T, N>& value){
    return value;
}
template<typename T, long unsigned N, long unsigned M, typename... Args>
auto cat(array < T, N>& first, array < T, M>& second, Args&... args){
    array<T, N + M> x;
    x = {};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N + M; i++) {
        if (i < N) {
            x[i] = first[i];
        }
        else {
            x[i] = second[i - N];
        }
     }
    cat(x, args...);
    return cat(x);
}
int main(){
    array<float, 3> vec1{ 1.0f,2.0f,3.0f };
    array<float, 3> vec2{ 4.0f,5.0f,6.0f };
    array<float, 6> vec3 = { 7.0f,8.0f,9.0f,10.0f,11.0f,12.0f };
    array<float, 3> vec4{ 7.0f,8.0f,9.0f };
    array<float, 6> vec5 = cat(vec1, vec2); // работает верно, получаем 123456
    array<float, 9> vec6 = cat(vec1, vec3); // работает верно, получаем 123789101112
    array<float, 9> vec7 = cat(vec1, vec2, vec4); //выдает ошибку
    return 0;
}
```

ошибка: `Ошибка C2440   инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "std::array<float,6>" в "std::array<float,9>"`    
Подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты решений, пока что все то, что пробую не приносит нужного результата.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, начнем с того, что вы возвращаете `cat(x)`, а надо

```
return cat(x, args...);
```

иначе результат сбора вы теряете.

Далее, вы собираете в кучку три массива по 3 элемента, а ждете массив из 12 элементов... (а, эту ошибку, пока я писал ответ, вы уже исправили... :))

Вот ваша немножко подправленная программа: https://ideone.com/6o8dT9

```
template<typename T, long unsigned N, long unsigned M, typename... Args>
auto cat(array < T, N>& first, array < T, M>& second, Args&... args)
{
    array<T, N + M> x;
    x = {};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N + M; i++) {
        if (i < N) {
            x[i] = first[i];
        }
        else {
            x[i] = second[i - N];
        }
     }
    return cat(x, args...);
}
 
int main(){
    array<float, 3> vec1{ 1.0f,2.0f,3.0f };
    array<float, 3> vec2{ 4.0f,5.0f,6.0f };
    array<float, 6> vec3 = { 7.0f,8.0f,9.0f,10.0f,11.0f,12.0f };
    array<float, 3> vec4{ 7.0f,8.0f,9.0f };
    array<float, 6> vec5 = cat(vec1, vec2); // работает верно, получаем 123456
    array<float, 9> vec6 = cat(vec1, vec3); // работает верно, получаем 123789101112
    auto /*array<float, 9>*/ vec7 = cat(vec1, vec2, vec4); //выдает ошибку
 
    for(auto z: vec7) cout << z << " ";
}
```

Comment: Анонимный минусатор, аргументируйте...

Comment: а его мысли неизвестны. Но вот сам код я бы в ответ добавил.

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, можно и добавить... Но там же аж две измененные строки...

Comment: теперь то ответ стал заметно лучше. Я свой вариант написал, но мне понадобилось три функции, а не две. А потом увидел, что минусатору пригляделся ответ и решил не трогать

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае полноценный вариант такого объединения написать не получится, так как для этого понадобились бы шаблоны с переменным числом параметров, каждый параметр которого состоял бы из переменного числа параметров и потом дважды раскладывался в плоский перечень:

```
return ::std::array<x_Item>{::std::forward<x_Array>(array[x_index]), ..., ...}:
```

По идее, если не нужно писать вариант для общего случая, то можно вручную сделать варианты шаблона для нужного количества входящих массивов.

В случае неопределенного количества входящих массивов придется так или иначе прибегать к поэлементному присваиванию. В этом плане код из вопроса в принципе пошел в верном направлении, если не считать тривиальную проблему с возвратом не того результата. Однако основная проблема заключается в наличии рекурсивного вызова шаблонной функции. Это тот самый code bloat, которым так любят пугать хейтеры шаблонов. Когда параметров шаблона только несколько штук, подобные конструкции вполне прокатывают, однако с ростом количества параметров они запросто кладут компилятор на лопатки. А еще создание временного массива на каждой итерации поднимают сложность операции до квадратичной. Так что более толковый вариант заключается в создании итогового массива сразу.

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

// Вспомогателный трейт для извлечения типа элемента массива из первого
// элемента пачки параметров. Предполагается, что такой же тип будет у всех
// остальныех элементов пачки параметров.
template
<
    typename x_Array
,   typename... x_ArrayRest
>
class
t_ItemTypeHelper final
{
    public:
    using
    t_Type = typename x_Array::value_type;
};

// Вспомогателный трейт для извлечения размера массива во время компиляции.
template
<
    typename x_Array
>
class
t_SizeHelper;

template
<
    typename x_Item
,   ::std::size_t x_size
>
class
t_SizeHelper<::std::array<x_Item, x_size>> final
:   public ::std::integral_constant<::std::size_t, x_size>
{};

template
<
    typename x_ResultArray
,   typename x_Array
>
[[nodiscard]] auto
Fill
(
    x_ResultArray & result
,   x_Array const & array
,   ::std::size_t result_index
)
{
    ::std::size_t index{};
    ::std::size_t const end_index{array.size()};
    for (;;)
    {
        result[result_index] = array[index];
        ++result_index;
        ++index;
        if (end_index == index)
        {
            break;
        }
        continue;
    }
    return result_index;
}

template
<
    typename... x_Array
>
[[nodiscard]] auto
Merge
(
    x_Array const &... array
)
{
    ::std::array
    <
        typename t_ItemTypeHelper<x_Array...>::t_Type
    ,   (t_SizeHelper<x_Array>::value + ...)
    >
    result;
    ::std::size_t result_index{};
    (static_cast<void>(result_index = Fill(result, array, result_index)), ...);
    return result;
}

int 
main()
{
    ::std::array<float, 3> vec1{1.0f,2.0f,3.0f};
    ::std::array<float, 3> vec2{4.0f,5.0f,6.0f};
    ::std::array<float, 6> vec3{7.0f,8.0f,9.0f,10.0f,11.0f,12.0f};
    ::std::array<float, 3> vec4{7.0f,8.0f,9.0f};
    [[maybe_unused]] ::std::array<float, 6> vec5{Merge(vec1, vec2)};
    [[maybe_unused]] ::std::array<float, 9> vec6{Merge(vec1, vec3)};
    [[maybe_unused]] ::std::array<float, 9> vec7{Merge(vec1, vec2, vec4)};
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAKzSrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAHP6kAA6oCoRODB7evgHSaRmOAqHhUSyx8Um2mPbFDEIETMQEOT5%2BgTV1WY3NBKWRMXGJyQpNLW15nWN9A%2BWVIwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzGHI3lgA1Cbbbs3ETACeJ9gmGgCCO3sHmMenBJcpmAD6BBeEChud0eZl2DH2XiOJzcyDG6CwVCBD2BAHoUccACIaEwATjMJgxXBMCSJWJMFgAYgTsRZbmSLG5qeS6TTtkyLNjCcT8fT/OyrPSMQSiQkBTScZiRTyRZyaXz6TjhdzMTTJPylQkKSryQl2QB2dk8mli8nykUG3nsoX03VczWS7ns200qn0jQOhLW43s%2BU0xmWwUao3k93s/00zki0lRp2G9mhm367WUn0a2Xk4O09ls%2Bm3B5oj1e8kmiy%2B8nh01WoPx5OuiMai00x422vxtNt%2BkV0vVu3prP0swAOm1ONdMtT9LV9LrzPVbuzHblPZjdoppA9Fql7OwHszfebNJZ5Il7IAbD7d7Hp8no8Sc6qJ1KPdtk9LiaSl3a%2Bfn0duNbeEj3OcRS7a0RRLM1iX8Qs50/P0JxpMDHVzQ1W3nO1G3JA8dTQ%2Bte0XctH2Q8cUIHQdgQITAWBSAxKOBaF6I0HEPi%2BZg2EOVRvnuYgLmuB5SDuZjPkYVhMEHcSOK4nirgAJUwMZ6O2PN7n2JgFEBB4CG%2BABJSiWAAFWEgAJWovmIQ4aGYWh6L1KxkSYlIvGiWg8GQEBGJxLwMiMDytMMr43gxQ4WJE9jOO43iQBAAA3MQvB%2BEKTjsx49SFbZktRX8yTxf92Rnft4NI1kOy3ANvUDO0SxPO03wSPsywsRUauTKdypFLUrxpTCLEzCCGwQ8kiwsW12o9Ps%2B26rtILqmswxK99csTAdZuW3NX3bMrCNXZNsIKraXU64sNTHYlzyWmkEnIzSqJopg6ORU5fOEtjXnC6S%2BMeJTgVU9SKO%2BIQ8AAL0wEzaDMpLGPuPTbvuz7GXsoTWNEyTdKo4EBKYqK4SxoGEskjJgcU5Sfo0qH/tx0HwdOLGCHQKLziuaFONRlh104gnMCBJSLLCMRgXchynJc5BDhpumQDCSjgAuWhvjQBgZkEaExZx4HfjZ74OaRFKrFSiH7Khm7aM5h74ceJiQpeyS5IULxaAICLGf4wTLeRt7eKJ%2Bj/Csb2GAwPAFFEYh0BMfwhTDw4mC8IhgQpOhrIeCAPM4m27Yd97jjMU9DmIeS0/RwT3auQ55bGTPs4Zj6MZxFWQA534c7z%2B3vjCLBVGBRYbIyzG69p1W8dbzB29skw9fSjza/rggS4EMvXBbhg29HixK8HDmIE7sfu5xfhzKT8f0s7hHl48wTc9t%2B3Q4sc%2B04XpeI5OILK6vwf27D/XzcVJjrGsG/m9fj%2BgkgGWGsAA8ex8mJ4CoIcCA89X6BUfocV%2BR9P5AJHhAr%2BOJoi5yYAAa0Ad/b%2BesMHy0cAweKBDFTEM/rnAgawGCNwvlpMBGVqEUSNndE2cMnpIzYOJYcRcPrayvlfP2%2BBA7NBDu/COUcY4PAALJxGAFwpOCNBEzwVtPcwp5%2BGR3eh3LuE9e7i2fsfR6GDXbsS0izfyINTJxCZlJXi/CbhRT8sJDy1cIBaQBsDSmDjTiCNcTFOKrxrCHH4SgoBX0EZ/wIJQyeuMG5xLvkPE%2BW8PIQBmI4ZAcs1LxNONFVAeAQ5KQgCk%2BBiC460FoOUpuBB1yV3XBUxeQ9FjLAieJTu4CaGYDocQBhcTAFsIeJLY4DwWBMDCBvQxCNa7P1OFQWgqA7rrjZNzaKmBkBElsocLgg4NBUFIEOQ5pBtgHOgaPNK295n6MWcs1Zhx1k7k2cgfEuzJAXNIP4L5OjDnHAyXM4x9M7luCWSshphxzwbK2WyXZeovmXVOTiL5XANCov2acrgJzLmAs/rcj29yIVrJuIcV5ap4WIq%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%3D%3D%3D)

Этот вариант можно улучшить, добавив использование `memcpy` вместо поэлементного копирования для тривиально копируемых типов и форвардинг для нетривиально копируемых.

Comment: Почему не `std::copy`?

Comment: Пробовала сделать изначально массив итогового размера и без рекурсии с помощью создания двумерного массива из всех `std::array`, которые подаются нам на вход:`T* C[sizeof ... (arrays)+1] = {first.data(), (arrays.data())...};`, но по итогу все равно выходила та же ошибка, хотя возвращала уже просто массив после всех итераций цикла (цикл получался в этом случае вложенным)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Можно было бы. И `::std::move` тоже. Fill мне тут вообще не нравится, в таком виде это тоже code bloat. Но это скорее из категории "можно улучшить".

Answer (score 2):

Попробую и я. Про ошибку уже рассказали. Про неэффективность тоже. Попробую предложить эффективный вариант, который можно понять (ну, я могу его понять). Он не длинный и все шаблоны функциональные - с ними иметь дело почему-то легче.

`cat_size` по списку массивов считает сумму их длин. Это будущая длина конкатенации:

```
constexpr std::size_t cat_size() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename Arg, typename... Args>
constexpr std::size_t cat_size(Arg &head, Args &... tail) {
    return head.size() + cat_size(tail...);
}
```

`cat_copy` получает один указатель и список массивов и копирует массивы по этому указателю один за другим (хвостовая рекурсия!):

```
template<typename T>
auto cat_copy(T * /* p */) {
}

template<typename T, typename Arg, typename... Args>
void cat_copy(T *p, Arg &head, Args &... tail) {
    p = std::copy(head.begin(), head.end(), p);
    cat_copy(p, tail...);
}
```

`cat` выполняет конкатенацию в один проход. Вычисляет сумму длин массивов, выделяет новый массив, копирует в него массивы из списка аргументов:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename... Args>
auto cat(const std::array<T, N> &head, Args &... tail) {
    std::array<T, cat_size(head, tail...)> result;
    cat_copy(result.begin(), head, tail...);
    return result;
}
```

Вызов `cat_size` вычисляется компилятором. `cat_copy` определён через хвостовую рекурсию. Это с высокой вероятностью позволит оптимизатору вызов `cat` превратить в объявление нового массива после которого идёт простыня из вызовов `std::copy`.

Есть и недостатки. Это не `constexpr`, а можно было бы сделать `constexpr`, хотя и сложно. Но это недостаток маленький. Большой недостаток что `cat` позволяет приведение типов, в том числе и сужающее. Можно массив `double` скопировать во `float` и не будет даже предупреждения. Исправление этого недостатка оставляю в качестве упражнения.